# How does the plan in the final battle solve the problem of Thanos?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

[With reference to this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/212300/116430) the most upvoted answer says that in *Avengers: Endgame* the plan was to return the

> Stones back to their timelines and **not** snap Thanos out of existence.

But how does this solve the problem when Thanos will continue to exist and still cause harm as he has access to the

> Pym particles and can potentially travel back to retrieve the returned Stones. Isn't the only way to end this would be Iron Man making the sacrifice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because when the Infinity Stones are returned to their time lines the alternate reality where that Thanos and his army are from will cease to exist.

> **The Ancient One:** The Infinity Stones create what you experience as the flow of time. Remove one of the stones, and that flow splits. Now this may benefit your reality. But my new one, not so much. In this new branched reality, without our chief weapon against the forces of darkness, our world will be overrun. Millions will suffer. So, tell me, doctor, can your science prevent all that?
>
> **Banner:** No. **But we can erase it.** Because once we're done with the stones, we can return each one into its own timeline at the moment it was taken. So, chronologically... In that reality.... it never left.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

Remember the scene where they have this conversation there is a diagram in the air, when the Ancient One removes one of the Infinity Stones a new time line shows up on said diagram but when Banner puts it back again the time line is erased.

This Thanos, his Children and the armies are from an alternate reality where the Power and Soul Stones were taken from. So when they put the Stones back into 2014 the Thanos and his forces would have been erased.

It's also worth noting, as Nathan K says in a comment, that the plan also stops the immediate problem of Thanos being able to get his hands on the Infinity Stones and snapping. They are removing them from harm's way.

Comment: And before someone comes and says "that's not how it works!" That depends on who you ask, the directors would disagree but the writers would agree. However, all that matters is that in universe this is what the characters believed would happen.

Comment: And if you prefer the directors' interpretation-- Even if those other timelines do continue to exist, taking the stones through the quantum portal does solve the immediate problem by getting them out of Thanos's reach for the moment.  Maybe this would have led to Thanos pursuing them through time and eventually catching them, or maybe he would have turned his weapons on the Earth in frustration.  In either case, it's one of Dr. Strange's loss scenarios.  But only he knew that at the time.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter what the characters in-universe believe it is. They are not all knowing. The only thing that matters is how it IS in-universe. To summarize the one timeline theory: 1. War Machine removes the stone. 2. Captain America returns the stone. 3. Timeline ceases to exist (Cap somehow survives, Quill who got knocked out starts dancing again) 4. Thanos travels from non-existence into main timeline. --- There are so many flaws in this, I don't understand why anybody (especially the writers) would prefer this against the multiverse theory.

Comment: @Chris Except this _is_ how it is in universe. The characters all say this is how it works. The writers say it is how it works and they wrote the thing! You're missing something here, that timeline where the stone is removed is an _alternate_ timeline. Quill does not start dancing again because that timeline is erased, it doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: So Captain America gets erased as soon as he returns the first stone?

Comment: @Chris No, why would he? The erasing isn't shown to be instant, remember the diagram the Ancient One uses, and he can hop skip out of there with the Space/Time GPS anyway.

Comment: I think the quote from the writers has been misinterpreted: the multiverse theory makes way more sense than the infinity stones themselves controlling timelines. The Ancient One uses the removal of a time stone as an *example* of how an alternate bad timeline would exist: removing and replacing infinity stones isn’t the only way to branch or erase timelines. Replacement of the time stone prevents the bad future where they’re defenceless against Dormammu. But the same would happen for any event, such as Loki’s escape. To “erase” that timeline’s bad future, they have to recapture Loki.

Comment: I don't see how this can be accurate, unless 2014 Gamora disappears when Cap returns the stones.  We don't actually _know_ she didn't, but I think if she had, there'd have been a mention of it.

Comment: @Bobson There's somewhat of a mention in that Quill is searching for Gamora at the end. It might be because she disappeared or it might be because she left at the end of the battle we don't know, it's left intentionally ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr** - There was no way (a debatable point) to undo the events of the timeline as we saw it, but they could sneak over to other timelines and fix the majority of the effects of The Snap.

The main problem is the somewhat confusing theory of time travel that the movies used, which is based on at least ***A*** version of time travel the comics have used.

According to the explanation, when you travel in time, you do not travel into your *own* past, but into an alternate timeline in which your appearance took place.  So taking the stones out of the timeline does not erase their existence in "our present", and does not negate Thanos being able to retrieve them.

So the recovery missions generate several new timelines where each of the stones no longer exist where they did in the main timeline.

But by returning the stones almost immediately after they were removed, the effect on said timelines is virtually nil.  So for example, the Ancient One only loses the use of the Time Stone for a brief period, not long enough to fail to defend the Sanctum.

Thanos' time trip generates *another* timeline, one where he simply and mysteriously blinked out of existence. That timeline never saw him collect the stones, and never suffered through The Snappening. The Thanos we saw at the end of the film was not the same Thanos we saw at the beginning, but one from a divergent timeline.

Comment: I have to say any time a writer uses time travel as a Deus ex machina, I lose a little respect. Maybe a lot...

Comment: _"Thanos' time trip generates another timeline"_ correct, _"That timeline never saw him collect the stones"_ correct but for the wrong reasons, that timeline is erased when Steve returns the stones. You're sort of right with your explanation but for the wrong reasons if I'm reading this right.

Answer (score 2):

The question asks about the *original* plan, so...

According to the original plan, there would be one and *only* one timeline. In this timeline, the sequence of events would have been:

1. Infinity stones are "borrowed" and immediately returned.
2. Thanos gets his hands on all of the infinity stones (i.e. Infinity War).
3. "The Snap".
4. Thanos destroys infinity stones.
5. Thor kills Thanos.
6. Infinity stones arrive from the past.
7. Undo "The Snap".
8. Infinity stones are returned to the past.

Past-Thanos following the Avengers back to their present was not part of the plan. If that hadn't happened, then — from the perspective of "the past" from which the stones were borrowed — nothing would have changed. Thanos would have eventually gotten the stones as he did "before", "The Snap" would have happened, and it would have been undone as in Endgame, because it would have all been *one* timeline.

Presumably, Thanos finding future-Nebula created a second timeline. When he subsequently invaded the Endgame timeline and was dusted, he would have ceased to exist in his own timeline¹, which presumably means that timeline still has infinity stones, while the Endgame timeline does not (unless someone created a second set off-screen before returning the "past" infinity stones).

(¹ ...or if he'd won and just not returned to his own timeline. Being dusted ensured that he *couldn't* return.)

Comment: _"The question asks about the original plan, so..."_ well no actually it specifically asks about the plan that was made up during the final battle.

Comment: Also the 2014 Thanos in 2023 is an alternate reality Thanos that would have been erased had Tony not snapped anyway when the Power and Soul Stones were returned to 2014 thus erasing the timeline.

Comment: I don't think that's true; he may have *left* his timeline after the stones were borrowed, but the events that led to him doing so occurred *before* that. It seems plausible that every time an avenger "inserted" into the past, that became a new timeline... one that didn't get ruined (as would have happened if the stones weren't returned), perhaps, but still new.